# Programa simples Arduino

Tags: c, arduino

Sou novo em programação.... O programa que estou tentando escrever para rodar no Arduino, vai comandar um circuito que tem dois botões. O botão 1 é para ligar um Led e ele executar a sequencia de piscadas. O outro, deve desligar todo o sistema. O primeiro botão funcionou, mas não consigo fazer o segundo botão desligar o LED. Será que alguém pode ajudar?

```
int led1 = 13;
int botao1 = 7;
int botao2 = 2;
int estadobotao1 = 0;
int estadobotao2 = 0;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(led1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(botao1, INPUT);
  pinMode(botao2, INPUT);

}

void loop()
{
estadobotao1 = digitalRead(botao1);

    if (estadobotao1 == HIGH) {
  while(estadobotao2 == LOW){ 

       digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
       delay(300);
       digitalWrite(led1,LOW);
       delay(300);
       digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
       delay(300);
       digitalWrite(led1,LOW);
       delay(300);
       digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
       delay(500);
       digitalWrite(led1,LOW);
       delay(500);
       digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
       delay(500);
       digitalWrite(led1,LOW);
       delay(500);
    estadobotao2 = digitalRead(botao2);
    }
        }
  if(estadobotao2 == HIGH){
    digitalWrite(led1,LOW);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Enquanto o programa estiver executando o código dentro do while nada irá acontecer se você apertar o botão de desligar, o programa só irá sair do while se você manter o botão 2 pressionado o tempo inteiro porque neste caso "estadobotao2 = digitalRead(botao2);" irá atualizar para HIGH.
Você poderia simplesmente colocar esse botão 2 em série para desligar tudo.
Também recomendo ativar o pull up e colocar um delay para evitar o bounce.

Comment: Boa noite! Obrigado pela resposta....Não consegui compreender amigo... O botão 2 em série com quem?

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que seja a troca de WHILE por DO WHILE, qualquer problema me avise:

```
int led1 = 13;
int botao1 = 7;
int botao2 = 2;
int estadobotao1 = 0;
int estadobotao2 = 0;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(led1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(botao1, INPUT);
  pinMode(botao2, INPUT);
}

void loop()
{
    estadobotao1 = digitalRead(botao1);
    if (estadobotao1 == HIGH) {
        do
        {
            digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
            delay(300);
            digitalWrite(led1,LOW);
            delay(300);
            digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
            delay(300);
            digitalWrite(led1,LOW);
            delay(300);
            digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
            delay(500);
            digitalWrite(led1,LOW);
            delay(500);
            digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
            delay(500);
            digitalWrite(led1,LOW);
            delay(500);
            estadobotao2 = digitalRead(botao2);
        }
        while(estadobotao2 == LOW);
    }
    if(estadobotao2 == HIGH)
    {
        digitalWrite(led1,LOW);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Como já está na função loop, você pode trocar esse while por if. Poderia usar uma variável auxiliar pra guardar o status do botão. Ou se quiser algo mais complexo procure por interrupção.